# How do I remove a WebSocket object from a JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, websocket

I am currently adding a WebSocket client object to an array so I can match it (by index) to another array of user information, to determine which user belongs to which client/socket/session.

```
var users = [];
var clients = [];
...
wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {

    clients.push(ws);
    var i = clients.indexOf(ws);
    if(i > -1) {
        users.push({
        id: i,
        user: "",
        room: "",
        client: clients[i],
    }); 
    }

    ws.on('close', function(ws) {
        var i = clients.indexOf(ws); //i = -1
        if(i > -1) { 
            // remove this client and user...
        }
    });

    ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
      // do stuff
    });
});
```

I am able to get the index of the `ws` object (which returns 0) so I am able to insert the object as part of the JSON object to the "users" array fine. But when I attempt to remove the same `ws` object when the connection is closed `-1` is returned for `indexOf(ws)`. But surely it should return `0` as it is the same object(connection) as previously used and is still present at index 0 in the clients array?

Why is indexOf() returning -1 in the "close" handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `close` event listener does not get a `WebSocket` as its first argument, if you're using the `ws` module in Node. The [docs say the first argument is closing `code` reason](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/7debd827d39925650bba5a270811ed82616f0eb1/doc/ws.md#event-close), not a socket.

Instead, you already have the socket in the outer `ws` variable. Don't shadow it with an argument named `ws`, and your code should work fine:

```
ws.on('close', function(code, message) {
    var i = clients.indexOf(ws);
    //...
});
```